# React Native, Change value From Child class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made 2 screens 1st home screen and 2nd for edit screen. I want to update the values from edit screen but when I click save button it shows an error `setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables` and display a blank home screen. Can someone please tell me how to update value from the child class? Below is my code, please help

home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    editMode: false.
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "John Cena",
        des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
        image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
      },
    ],
  };

  addPost = (posts) => {
    posts.key = Math.random().toString();
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        post: [...prevState.post, posts],
        modal: false,
      };
    });
  };

  onEdit = (data) => {
    this.setState({ post: { title: data }, editMode: false });
  };

 

  render() {
    if (this.state.editMode)
      return <EditScreen item={item} onEdit={this.onEdit} />;
    return (
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <Modal visible={this.state.modal} animationType="slide">
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            
              <AddPost addPost={this.addPost} />
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
            
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ editMode: true })}
                style={styles.Edit}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="playlist-edit"
                  color="green"
                  size={35}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Card>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
                <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                    {item.title}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={2}>
                    {item.des}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </Card>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Screen>
```

Edit.js

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="position"
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 100}
      >
        <Image style={styles.image} source={item.item} />
        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppTextInput value={item.title} />
          <AppTextInput value={item.des} />
        </View>
        <AppButton
          text="Save"
          onPress={() => {
            onEdit(this.state);
            this.props.navigation.goBack("Home");
          }}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I'm also getting a warning

`This can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state for more details.`

Comment: use redux for creating global state.....

Comment: I can't, I need to do it without redux and context it's my task

Comment: u cannot send setState function in navigation param because both pages are different , ListDetails is not a child of ListDetails, you have to use redux or cotext api

Comment: Tell this to my boss

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though `ListDetails` is not actually a child of `Home`. If it were you could pass the `onEdit` function down as props.

You should not pass it as navigation params because when you leave the `Home` page it will be unmounted and you won't be able to update the state.

One way to achieve what you want is to use the Context api to setup a store for your application state.

Check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Edit, without context:

You will need to move the `ListDetails` component inside the `Home` component as a child. You can keep a value in state to check if you are in edit mode. Something like this maybe:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedItem: undefined,
    modal: false,
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "John Cena",
        des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
        image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
      },
    ],
  };

  addPost = (posts) => {
    posts.key = Math.random().toString();
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        post: [...prevState.post, posts],
        modal: false,
      };
    });
  };

  onEdit = (data) => {
    this.setState({ post: { title: data }, editMode: false, selectedItem: undefined });
  };

  render() {
    const { editMode, selectedItem } = this.state;

    if (editMode && selectedItem) return <ListDetails item={selectedItem} onEdit={onEdit} />

    return (
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <Modal visible={this.state.modal} animationType="slide">
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
              <AddPost addPost={this.addPost} />
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ editMode: true, selectedItem: item })}
                style={styles.Edit}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="playlist-edit"
                  color="green"
                  size={35}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Card>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
                <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                    {item.title}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={2}>
                    {item.des}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </Card>
            </>
```

Comment: Ok where should I pass props item and onEdit in ListDetail screen??

Comment: const { item, onEdit } = this.props;
onEdit(this.state);

Comment: `can't fint variable: item` I updated my code in my question check it

Comment: Updated the code, try that. You need to keep track of which item you are editing.

Comment: bcoz it's displaying no value on it and showing error `Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`.`

Comment: Can you confirm that the item is being passed in correctly into the Edit component, and that you are accessing the right property for the value of the text input. Seems like it is being passed a object instead of a string.

Comment: I updated my ListDetail code in my question check it

Comment: You are passing the item directly to each field. you need to access the properties for each. item.title or item.image for the image component. I'm not sure what fields are on the object so you'll have to figure that part out

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot :) but how can update text? Like if do onChangeText i need pass some function into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222650/discussion-between-emiliokyp-and-kanwarjeet-singh).